# Control NSMallocException

Tags: ios, objective-c

The message is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSMallocException',

Reason: 'Out of memory. We suggest restarting the application.
```

If you have an unsaved document, create a backup copy in Finder, then try to save

I get to give me some results after calling google maps api